# How to avoid the (Author not verified) message when installing a Firefox XPI file

Tags: firefox, plugins, signing, xpi

What do I need to do to avoid the "Manual Install" in Firefox for a Plugin and where do I have to go or what do I have to do to avoid the (Author not verified) message when downloading a Plugin. Ideally I would like to initiate the installation of the Plugin automatically and if I need to sign the Plugin somehow to show that it is not doing any kind of malicious things I would like to do that as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Signing the XPI will remove the warning message but there is still no automatic way to install extensions or plugins.

I've written a few posts on the [XPI Format](http://o-regan.org/2007/04/11/firefox-xpi-internal-structure/) and a howto for [signing](http://o-regan.org/2007/04/23/extension-signing-with-xpisigner/) using a java commandline tool.

The tool [XPISigner](https://code.google.com/p/xpisigner/) simplifies the process considerably and is integratable into build systems.

Comment: "XPI Format" and "signing" links are no longer valid.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [official tutorial](http://www.mozdevgroup.com/docs/pete/Signing-an-XPI.html), which only deals with signing the XPI. I don't believe it's possible to install the plug in automatically for rather obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me on FF 2.0.3:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
<!--
function install (aEvent)
{
  var params = {
    "Foo": { URL: aEvent.target.href,
             IconURL: aEvent.target.getAttribute("iconURL"),
             Hash: aEvent.target.getAttribute("hash"),
             toString: function () { return this.URL; }
    }
  };
  InstallTrigger.install(params);

  return false;
}
-->
</script>

<a href="http://www.example.com/foo.xpi"
  iconURL="http://www.example.com/foo.png"
  hash="sha1:28857e60d043447c5f4550853f2d40770b326a13"
  onclick="return install(event);">Install Extension!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [official tutorial](https://www.mozdevgroup.com/docs/pete/Signing-an-XPI.html)  which deals with signing the XPI. Automatic installation isn't possible because of the security considerations.